# Java labels. To be or not to be

Tags: java

Before I start this question I know the java 'goto' is a big no go.

So I've been writing a program and I have some indented Loops and statements and I need to `BREAK` multiple on command. Rather than having a load of `boolean` variables and `if(!<booleanName>) BREAK;` statements throughout these loops and statements what is everyone's opinions on using labels to break them using the `BREAK <label>` statement?

e.g.

```
 for(...) {

      indented_example_loops:     // Label name
           for(...) {
                for(...) {
                     if(match) break indented_example_loops;
                     // ^ Break statement to break the 2 for loops at once
                }
           }

 }
```

Perfectly okay? Okay to do occasionally? Completely avoid? or should i go to a corner and call the Devil to take my soul?

Comment: I for one think your problem is the deep nesting, not a use or abuse of labels and goto

Comment: The nesting is necessary as its lists nested inside lists i.e. Group > Member > Emails/Addresses/Phone-Numbers

Comment: Put the nested code in a separate method and use `return` instead of `break`. Structured programming was invented more than 40 years ago (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_program_theorem) for good reasons.

Comment: If you think functionally, using a nested loop + break as you do should correspond to a flat map (http://twitter.github.com/effectivescala/#Functional%20programming-%60flatMap%60) combined with a filter on the result (`takeWhile` ?). Reinterpreting your code in this way can give you some hints on how to restructure the code.

Comment: @Giorgio, you should make that an answer.

Comment: `break`, `continue`, `throw`, `switch`, and `return` are all forms of the much maligned `goto`.  Some of this is warranted, some is not. Labels can make these structures easier to read or harder. Treat them all with respect.

Comment: @MichaelT: You forgot `if`, `while`, `for`, `func()`, `finally`, etc.

Comment: If it is clearer than other options, then do it.  If people don't like it, let them refactor your code and take responsibility for any bugs it introduces.

Comment: @ThomasEding to that extent, all control structures are... the ones I named are just a bit more blatant about the "go to this line" in the code.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's all about readability and ease of understanding.

The easiest to understand loops are those with simple end conditions and no breaks at all. So if you can write your loops like that, do it.

```
while (someCondition) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Next comes the loop with a simple end condition and a single break:

```
while (someCondition) {
  // do stuff
  if (otherCondition) {
    break;
  }
  // maybe some more stuff
}
```

Everything that's more complex than this is a potential problem. A break with a label is always tricky, because you'll have to hunt for the label to find out which statement/block the break *escapes from* (i.e. the break will continue *after* the labeled block/statement).

The worst kind (the one you *almost always* want to avoid) is a nested loop where you break *somewhere in the middle*.

```
while (someCondition) {
  myLabel:
  for (Foo foo : getAllFoos()) {
    for (Bar bar : foo.getBars()) {
      // do stuff
      if (someCondition(bar)) {
        break myLabel; // BAD!
      }
      // some more stuff
    }
  }
}
```

The problem here is that the actual flow of processing becomes really hard to follow. If you start having code like this, then you should definitely refactor it.

A common refactoring is to extract one (or more) nested loops into a method and turning the `break` into a `return`. This has the added benefit of giving a name to that piece of the code. If the name is chosen well, then that will help greatly in understanding the code.

Comment: Thanks, ill take this into account. I guess using methods and return statements would give me the same result and be a lot easier to read

Comment: +1 even if I dislike `break` in any case (except `switch`).

Comment: @UwePlonus: I think on the "low end" (simple breaks), it's mostly a matter of taste, and I won't argue against avoiding it altogether. The *most* important part (in my opinion) is to avoid the really hard to read constructs with nested loops and multiple break labels. Those are mind-benders and not usually worth the trouble.

Answer (score 6):

**You are opening yourself up to spaghetti code**

While the language allows you to do this, it is not good practice. There are many alternative looping structures that will achieve the same objective and make your code much more readable.

Essentially, labels and gotos are a holdover from assembly language code (which is all about labels and gotos). It really has no place in higher level languages.

Comment: What looping structures would you advise?  Why do you think a break is a goto?

Comment: The approach that @JoachimSauer has given is the correct way to implement this. The break is going to an earlier label which is not as readable as, for example, a return statement from a method.

Answer (score 1):

**Separate the iteration and the processing** by encapsulating the iteration.

Iterating over multi-level structures with nested loops leads to applications where most of the code is looping noise.  To process all the `Level2Thing`s in a `Level0Thing`, replace your nested loops with this:

```
for (Level2Thing t2: topThing.level2Things()) {
   // do something
}
```

where `level2Things()` returns an `Iterable<Level2Thing>`.

You can find some sample code for encapsulating nested iterations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2298100/229810).

Comment: Suppose the loops were for x and y over some integer range, I don't see how that can be done in a simple way.  I suspect it impacts performance.

Comment: @FlorianF: you build an iterator that holds values for x and y and increments y to the limit, then resets y and increments x.  The performance impact will be small assuming you are doing anything interesting inside the loop.  Basically the overhead is the one-time iterator allocation and the calls to hasNext() and next().

Comment: OK, but that means you create an Iterator that creates and returns Tuples of 2 Integers.  Then you unpack the Tuple into x and y.  It is not exactly simple.  Unless you have many similar double-loops, it is overkill to abstract them out in an iterator.  For simple cases, breaking out of 2 loops is still the best option IMHO.

Comment: @FlorianF: depends on your idea of simple.  An iterator has a very simple interface: hasNext() and next().  So it's clear *what* the iterator does.  The iterator itself is pretty simple too after you've written one.  Or you could just use Guava.  The key is to think first about the *what* and then worry about the *how*.  *What* you are doing is iterating over some set of things.  *How* you are doing it is by traversing a two-level structure.  That *how* could change, so you don't want multiple copies of that nested-loop structure scattered about.

Answer (score -3):

For very deeply nested loops or complex code flow, I often declare anonymous `Runnable`s. While not directly related to the question, it is still relevant. I'm sure there is a better example than this, but it's a start.

```
public int ComplexFunction() {
    final Integer value = new Integer();
    final Boolean quit = new Boolean(false);

    final Runnable doTest = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (value.intVal() > 100) {
                quit = new Boolean(true);
            }
        }
    }


    while (true) {
        value = new Integer(value.intVal() + 5);
        doTest.run();
        if (quit.booleanVal() == true) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this seems to be missing an example of _deeply nested loop_ showing how recommended approach is expected to work and explanation of how it would be better than using label

Comment: I don't see a label in that code at all. You may wish to read [Oracle's tutorial on branching statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) - in particular pay attention to the BreakWithLabelDemo.  As an aside, please endeavor to have code that compiles and uses best practices when giving example code (the `new Integer()` and `new Boolean()` calls are particularly problematic to my eyes beyond other issues).